# Pygame expanding sprite has collision issues

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am creating a game in which two players fire their tanks at one another to try and kill the other player. My current system uses a bullet to fly towards the target, and once it hits the ground, an explosion sprite is created, that expands over time. I currently have an issue where the expanding explosion sprite will collide with the tank before it actually reaches the tank. This is an issue as I wish to deduct damage based on the distance the explosion sprite is away from the tank. 
This is my current code:

```
def explode(self, x, y, alive):
    explosionList.add(self)
    explosionList.draw(gameDisplay)
    self.rect.center = x, y
    damage = 100
    collideTank = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, tankList, False)
    tank = False
    for i in range(20):
        damage -= 5
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if len(collideTank) > 0 and tank == False:
            tank = True
            collideTank[0].damageTank(alive, damage)
        self.image = explosionImage
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, ((i + 1) * 3, (i + 1) * 3))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        explosionList.clear(gameDisplay, background)
        explosionList.draw(gameDisplay)
        pygame.display.update()
    explosionList.clear(gameDisplay, background)
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pygame.sprite.spritecollide
```

uses `rect` of both sprites to determine the collision. It's very likely that the two rectangles overlap, even if the graphics say otherwise. You might consider smaller `rect` representations of your sprites or maybe using

```
pygame.sprite.collide_circle(left, right)
```

could help.